# What is the difference between DNS-over-HTTPS and DNSSEC?

Tags: dns, dnssec, dns-over-https

I was just introduced to the Domain Name System Security Extensions (DNSSEC) and it sounds very similar to the concept of DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) and DNS-over-TLS: to add privacy and security into DNS lookups.

What are the main differences between these protocols? Do they compete/serve the same goals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNSSEC just signs answers, to check integrity and preserve DNS cache poisoning from unauthorized fake "servers". With DNSSEC, any eavesdropper can:

- listen traffic
- understand "this is DNS"
- watch domain names for request/responses.

DOH is DNS over HTTPS. There is:

- traffic encrypted
- eavesdropper cannot understand - is this DNS or web http.
- eavesdropper unable to see contains of requests/answers.

Advantage of DNSSEC - more quick.
Advantage of DOH - more private.

Comment: "Advantage of DNSSEC - more quick." This makes no sense. "more quick" than that? As for "Advantage of DOH - more private." no this is not so clear cut, it depends on your network and who you contact as nameserver (what are its privacy policies?)

Comment: Great answer by olegarch, Thanks!